# Flash newbie- Can I create web apps (or websites) that can be accessed from browser in mobile devices viz ios/android/blackberry

Tags: ios, flash, apache-flex, air

I am very new to Flash and I read a lot of articles that Flash was not supported on ios until recently.

From what I understand, Adobe AIR runtime enables desktop apps created in Flash to be seen in ios/android/others.

What I want to do is create a simple website/web app using Flash (with Flex/AIR- any one of the SDKs) - but in such a way that the same website can be accessed with the browser in desktop/tablet/mobile devices-- including iphone/android. And I want the site to consist of HTML/JS/CSS/SWF files...I am OK if different SWF files are required for each type of device...Can such a website be created in Flash? Because in many sites it is mentioned that FLash is not supported on ios devices, but some sites also mention that native apps can be created using Flash which work in ios devices... But I am looking to create flash-powered websites that work across all mobiles(including ios/android/blackberry/pcs/tablets)...Also, if this can be done, then what are the IDEs that I can use for such dev work? Finally, can I use the Flex SDK for creating such web apps?

Answer (score 2):

> Adobe AIR runtime enables desktop apps created in Flash to be seen in
>   ios/android/others.

Adobe AIR can be used to create desktop apps for Windows and Mac.  And native mobile applications for iOS, Android, and the Blackberry Playbook.  So, your understanding is correct.

> I am very new to Flash and I read a lot of articles that Flash was not
>   supported on ios until recently.
>
> From what I understand, Adobe AIR runtime enables desktop apps created
>   in Flash to be seen in ios/android/others.
>
> What I want to do is create a simple website/web app using Flash (with
>   Flex/AIR- any one of the SDKs) - but in such a way that the same
>   website can be accessed with the browser in desktop/tablet/mobile
>   devices-- including iphone/android.

You're out of luck, then.  You cannot access Flash in the browser on iOS; and it is not supported on many Android devices.

Native apps are different than browser based apps.